# Why is the Stack Overflow Help Center ignoring my question?

Tags: support, help-center

I submitted a question via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/other) link and have gotten no recognition of having even submitted a question. Nor has the email sent directly to team@stackoverflow.com received any response.

Are there prerequisites to having a question answered that I am missing?

Comment: What kind of support question did you have?

Comment: Patience. That's the keyword. The team is busy, it's only a small team and very big network of sites. Give it at least one full day. If it's something really urgent that need immediate action and can be discussed  in public bring it here on Meta.

Comment: How long ago did you submit your question?

Comment: If you want to merge [this account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1930040/joe) with [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1945578/joe) please read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @TimPost The email I sent on January 3rd. The form I submitted to the Help Center yesterday morning.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That's exactly the issue. Problem is one of them (the one with which I answered the question) is unregistered. I read somewhere here on Meta (can't find it at the moment) to flag the answer and request a merge, but my registered account does not have enough reputation points to flag.

Comment: I think our 'help' [needs more 'help'](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08xQLGWTSag).

Comment: @Joe do both accounts have the same email address?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you submitted the `/help` form before yesterday, it may have unfortunately have been lost in limbo. There was an issue with some submissions that were deleted by gmail (our email provider). This was fixed yesterday.

As far as the email you sent to team@ goes: Assuming you did that just recently, the community team (who handle those emails) may just not have gotten to it yet. They're all in the US or Canada, so it's 7am or earlier there right now.

Comment: You mean gimbo!

Comment: The email to team@ was sent on Jan 3

Comment: My guess is that this was the issue. I resubmitted the help form and got a reply within a few hours.